# Как реализовать скил "Poison" ? Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Есть абстрактный класс Creature от которого наследуются два класса: Rogue, Goblin(в этих классах пара скиллов и статы).
Есть класс Fight(в нем реализован выбор скиллов и их применение) который наследуется от Monobehaviour. 
В общем хочу сделать скилл который при успешном срабатывании будет попускать противника каждый ход, с возможностью настакивать эффект, но не могу понять как его реализовать. 
Я так понял что нужно делать event в fight и подписыватся на него из классов существ. Я создаю event в классе Fight, но в классах Goblin/ Rogue не могу подписаться на него, так как его не видно.
Если же делать event в родительском классе Creature - то не могу объявить событие в классе Fight.
Как блин этот яд реализовать?))

Answer (score 4):

- Выделите здоровье в отдельный компонент с которым работают все классы. Это позволит стандартизировать обработку урона/лечения/баффов/дебаффов
- Выделите обработчик эффектов в отдельный компонент, он будет работать со здоровьем, и обрабатывать все что навешено на существо, с учетом времени.
- Добавьте эффект, яд, который можно передать в обработчик эффектов, на какое либо существо.

Это общая схема, детали очень зависят от архитектуры, жанра итд.

Comment: Ответ кажется логичным, но я много-го не понимаю, например: что такое компонент и как вынести в него здоровье, что такое обработчик эффектов и как его создать. 
На досуге постараюсь нагуглить как реализовать все эти пункты=)
Большое спасибо за ответ =)